# How to keep only necessary workbook in excel using powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having few excel files where each file have multiple workbooks.

Assume following are the workbook names.

```
Introduction
Testcase
Testresult
```

Also assume all the xls files are under same folder (For ex: C:\Servers)

```
Testsample.xlsx
TestExecution.xlsx    and few more xlsx files ...
```

I want to create resultant files where only testresult workbook should be there.

Resultant files like ,

Testsample-res.xlsx
   TestExecution-res.xlsx
   and few more resultant xlsx files

How to keep only the testresult workbook in new xls files? (Using powershell script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will **move** the Testresult sheet to a new excel document (replace Move() with Copy() to leave the original sheet in the source doc):

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible=$true
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Add('D:\Book1.xlsx')
$wb.Sheets.Item('Testresult').Move()
$xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs('D:\Testresult.xlsx')
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Buddy , It works if it has single excel file. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier. I am not having just one xls files. I am having 4 or 5 xlsx files. I was trying to put your solution inside foreach loop and it throws exception."you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." I have edited my question a bit.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have written you code inside a function and call it through foreach loop. It works fine. Your answer is accepted